# Why is my NETGEAR AC750 Wifi extender connecting at 780 Mbps, when it supposedly only supports 433Mbps operation in 5 GHz?

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-extender

[image]
[image]

I have a Netgear wifi extender EX3700 AC750. The images attached are the current screenshots of the Entender's configuration page. The product features sheet states that "Connection speed: 2.4 Ghz-300 Mbp, 5 Ghz-433 Mhz". However, when I use this extender to connect to the 5 Ghz network of the main router, it has a connection speed higher than 433 Mhz. Normally, it was 733 Mhz, but I don't know why it's jumped to 780 Mhz, recently. I think it can connect at 733 Mhz, because it uses kind of a proprietary feature, called "fast-lane" technology, which can utilize both 2.4 Ghz and 5 Ghz bands to created a high-speed connection( 300 + 433 = 733 Mbps makes sense). But it might be not, it might be the Wifi configuration of the Extender( the number of antennas, and spatial streams). This Extender appears to have 2 antennas. And I'm not sure about the 5 Ghz wireless mode set at the main router( because I've been renting a room in a house, have no access to the main router. I only have the wifi password). I guess the 5 Ghz band is set like: 5 Ghz- enabled, 5 Ghz Wireless mode- 802.11 n/ac( since my Netgear USB wifi adapter N600 dual-band can see the 5 Ghz wifi network broadcasted directly from the router).

I'm wondering about the Wifi configuration on this wireless connection, how many spatial streams that it's using. I suppose it's using 2 spatial streams on both 5 Ghz Wireless modes N, AC ; and the 5 Ghz channel width is 40 Mhz to get the connection speed at 733 Mbps (150+150 **+** 216+216 = 733 Mbps), because the AC wireless mode on 40 Mhz channels should have a PHY speed at around 216 Mbps for each spatial stream. That's my thought, but I'm not sure. Any suggestions?

P/S: You might notice that there are no devices currently connected on the extended Wifi networks. This is because my desktop is using a wired connection( the Extender has a 100 Mbps Ethernet port for Ethernet-enbled devices). Normally, I use the extended Wifi networks for portable devices, such as my phone.

Comment: Instead of looking at the values your Wifi extender claims to provide (but actually those are just theoretical values shown to impress the users) I would test the actual network bandwidth if the Wifi manages to really get 100MBit Ethernet speed through it.

Comment: Haven't you answered your own question in paragraphs one and two?

Comment: I was not talking about maximum connection speed values display. Those are theoretically and are only valid for the first network segment (in this case the Ethernet connection). I was talking about performing an real test (e.g. iperf3) for measuring the actual available speed between your PC and a second system connected via Ethernet to your router.

Comment: @Robert I did test it. My desktop is connected directly to the Ethernet port on the Extender. Windows 10 shows a connection speed of 100 Mbps. And, the browser speed test displays the result of 90 Mbps( download), 11 Mbps( upload). The Ethernet port on this Extender is only capable of 100 Mbps output. But, the point I'm mentioning here is about wireless-networking concepts.

Comment: @Robert I haven't tested the available speed between my PC directly to the house's main router, because the location that my desktop is placed , my wifi adapters got medium to low wifi signals. The internet connection dropped very often. That's why I had to buy an extender and put it somewhere in my room that I guess is closest to main router, in order to get strong wifi singals.

Comment: @JW0914 No, what I talk in paragraph 2 is just what I think, because that explains the connection speed of 733 Mbps. But I'm not quite sure about that; since, if so, the Extender must be using 4 spatial streams ( 2 spatial streams on 5 Ghz wireless N mode, 2 spatial streams on 5 Ghz wireless AC mode). Can 2 antennas support 4 spatial streams?

Comment: @Robert The values shown on the configuration page are not theoretical, I'm pretty sure it's real; because if the Extender is placed at a different location, the signal strength and the connection speed shown is dropped to around 350 Mbps.